# Nothing is happening when saving something from textbox (php) into mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am not sure this code has been written right. I'm trying to save datas into mySQL from text boxes. I think something will be in creating table and saving users into it.

```
<?php

if($_POST['go'])
{
    if(!$_POST['adminf'] || !$_POST['adminj'] || !$_POST['phone'])
    {
        echo 'Don't leave boxes empty!';
    }
    else
    {
        $connect = mysql_connect('host','login','pass')or die("Not good mySQL!");
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`adminf` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`adminj` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;",$connect);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`adminf`, `adminj`, `phone`) VALUES('".$_POST['adminf']."', '".$_POST['adminj']."', '".$_POST['phone']."');",$connect);
        echo 'Done!<br />';
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="#">
    Name: <input type="text" name="adminf" /><br />
    Code: <input type="text" name="adminj" /><br />
    Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="GO!" /><br />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You've got a parse error here: `echo 'Don't leave boxes empty!';` Use double quotes around the string or escape the apostrophe.

Comment: You're also going to get somebody telling you to use mysqli instead of plain mysql :)

Comment: @mopo922: you forgot to mention that someone will (and should) point out the SQL injection vulns here also `;-)`. Adrian - don't put this live, it's not safe to do so.

Comment: Thanks, my God, I am blind seriously.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a parse error here:

```
echo 'Don't leave boxes empty!';
```

Use double quotes around the string:

```
echo "Don't leave boxes empty!";
```

or escape the apostrophe:

```
echo 'Don\'t leave boxes empty!';
```

Answer (score 0):

everything is ok, you only need to escape the apostrophe.

```
echo 'Don\'t leave boxes empty!';
```

and the string from POST should be validated first.

Comment: What do you mean under validating?